# Is using a transformer at reduced voltage a bad idea?

Tags: voltage, transformer, measurement, isolation

My Google is failing me.

I want to make an isolated AC voltmeter capable of working at 120 or 240 VAC.

I've found a suitable 240 volt to 5 volt transformer to use (current capacity doesn't matter - the measurement will be at very high impedance).

What would it do if it were fed 120 volts? Ideally the transformer would simply output 2.5 volts, but I have a memory of transformers getting very cranky when fed the wrong voltage.

Comment: The frequency matters.

Comment: The transformer in question is rated for 50/60 Hz.

Comment: It sounds like what you want to do is build a power supply for a voltmeter by using a transformer with a 240V 50-60Hz primary and a 5V secondary and connecting that transformer's primary to either 120V or 240V, 50-60Hz  mains.  If that's true, what will it take to run your voltmeter in terms of DC voltage and current? In other words, what does the output of the power supply need to look like?

Comment: This device has a separate isolated DC power supply. This transformer would serve purely a measurement function. And I want AC output so that I can perform peak detection to facilitate power factor calculations (the same device has a current transformer based ammeter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is generally right in his comment. But what you *seem* to have here is a 240V 50Hz transformed that you want to use at 120V 60Hz and at a current much below the rated one. In general [60Hz transformers may overheat when used at 50 Hz](https://sound-au.com/articles/50-60hz.htm#s40). But not viceversa, and not at low load loads, so this isn't a great concern here.

But you need to beware that any transformer will output voltage above the rated one when running open circuit or at low load. So don't expect exactly 2.5V. In fact if the transformer is low power one (<10VA) you can easily have 50% more voltage at the output than what it's rated for at max current.

Comment: Is a potential solution to the load issue a load resistor across the secondary?

Comment: If you need "exactly" (in the sense of very close to) 2.5V in your circuit, then you should consider some kind of voltage regulation. A resistor may waste a lot of energy as heat because you may need a pretty low value to get close to 2.5V, depending on the transformer's current rating. If you intend to rectify the 2.5V to DC then there are easy solutions for voltage regulation. Otherwise [not so easy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator#AC_voltage_stabilizers)...

Comment: Well, regulation is the opposite of the goal. The purpose is to indirectly measure the voltage of the primary.

Comment: I see. In that case the only problem would be calibrating your measuring circuit for the actual voltage you'd get from your transformer when it is fed a well-known input.

Comment: @nsayer, a voltage divider is all that's beeded if the output voltage is too high for your purposes. loading the secondary will reduce acuracy and waste energy.

Comment: A 60Hz unloaded transformer will likely overheat more at zero loads on 50Hz so it should definitely be a concern. The overheating is due to magnetising current saturating the core and is not load related.

Comment: The transformer I'm considering is spec'd for 50/60 Hz.